# launch two actions in one button ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, vb.net

I'm developing a comment page in `asp.net`, this my page :

```
<form action="#">
<p><textarea id="textArea" rows="5" cols="30"></textarea></p>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<p>Add some comments to the page</p>
```

And this is my javascript code :

```
window.onload = initAll;

function initAll() {
document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].onsubmit = addNode;
}

function addNode() {
var inText = document.getElementById("textArea").value;
var newText = document.createTextNode(inText);
var newGraf = document.createElement("p");
newGraf.appendChild(newText);
var docBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
docBody.appendChild(newGraf);
return false;
}
```

Until then, everything is fine, but I want when the user clicks the `submit` button, the button will trigger another action that will save the comment in the database.

How can I do this thing ?

Comment: As a general tip, if you want to interact with controls on the server in C# (not on the client in javascript), using asp .NET controls (e.g. asp:TextBox and asp:Button) instead of HTML controls may help.  This way, you can refer to the control by id (e.g.,  this.textArea and this.btnSubmit), and reap other benefits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you have a wrapper and still make it one function?

The `addNode` could have code to do both maybe based on something in the form?

You could have a submit function that wraps the `addNode` and `addComment`.

eg:

```
function handleSubmit()
{
    addNode();
    addComment();
    return false;
}
```

**EDIT:** Since you want to call server code you have a couple of options.  You can do it all via ajax and you would just need to implement the `addComment` function to call a server side event.  See this article if you need help doing so:

http://www.dexign.net/post/2008/07/16/jQuery-To-Call-ASPNET-Page-Methods-and-Web-Services.aspx

The easiest way would be to change your button to an ASP.NET button and then implement the button click event which would call your server side method although this would cause a full page refresh.

A hybrid of the two, which is very easy to implement, would be to use an `UpdatePanel`.  When you clicked your button you would get the look and feel of the AJAX solution but only need to know how to do all the server side code and let the `UpdatePanel` handle all the AJAX work.  This method is a little heavier than just doing a raw ajax call but it is significantly more simple to do.

You can read up on `UpdatePanels` at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001.aspx

Comment: I've just found this code in internet, but I think that this javascript code cannot access to other controls in the page like Label or something else, and couldn't connect to database. !!!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using an HTML input tag, use asp:Button, like so:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
```

What this says is, use a Button that calls the "btnSubmit_Click" method whenever it is clicked on, and run this on the server (not on the client machine).

Then in your code-behind (you do have a code-behind, right?  e.g., nameOfPage.aspx.cs), you can add the aforementioned btnSubmit_Click method:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
    // interact with database here.
}
```

Comment: use a Button that calls the "btnSubmit_Click" method whenever it is clicked on !!! HOW ?

Comment: @AZIRAR: only your server should talk to the database , not your client browser. The client browser sends the data to the server, which saves it to the database.